# Downgrading TensorFlow from 1.15 to 1.14 not working

Tags: tensorflow, downgrade

I have a colab notebook which was running tf1.15.0. I need to downgrade it to 1.14.0. In a cell, it run the following:

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow==1.15.0
!pip install tensorflow==1.14.0
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

However, it outputs:

```
> 1.15.0
```

What am I doing wrong please?

CS

Comment: what happens when you restart the notebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF you have `import tensorflow` cell before uninstall, you may need to restart notebook to make it effective.

IF you have not, make sure you are running the correct pip in the same python environment as the notebook, such as:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install xx
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have TensorFlow-GPU installed in the system? Because this is the same issue I was facing earlier, so try downgrading TensorFlow-GPU.

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.14
```

or any other version of `tensorflow-gpu`.